# Are USB hard disks less reliable for backups?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, sata

A colleague told me that it is not recommended to use USB hard disks due to the lack of inherent integrity checking of copied files. I am looking for details on that. In what respect is copying to a USB device different from copying to a hard disk connected via e.g. SATA? If anybody has further sources/information on that, I would appreciate sharing it with me.

Comment: Please don't cross-post on different sites. http://superuser.com/questions/812915/are-usb-hard-disks-less-reliable-for-backups

Comment: Mobile drives in general are less reliable purely because they tend to get knocked about.  But then your backup needs to be away from your pc, preferably offsite to provide decent protection.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know integrity check of copied file is done (if at all done) on much higher level. It is up for OS or software that performs copying to perform the integrity check.

Regarding USB and SATA - main differences are transfer speed and availability of power in the connector (SATA does not include power) - but I assume these you already know about it and it is not relevant to the actual question.

So my assumption would be that your colleague's statement was incorrect.